# Java interface methods passing super type

Tags: java, interface, overriding

I have an interface that has methods like

```
public interface IFilterManager {
    public FilterAbs getFilter(String filterName);
    public void saveFilter(FilterAbs filter);
}
```

I then have a class that implements these.

```
public class FilterManager implements IFilterManager {
    @Override
    public JobFilter getFilter(String filterName) {
    //Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void saveFilter(JobFilter jobFilter)
    //Do stuff
    }
}
```

JobFilter is a concrete class of FilterAbs, eclipse has no problems with getFilter I'm confused why it has an issue with saveFilter. The error is

> The method saveFilter(JobFilter) of type MappedJobFilterManager must
>   override or implement a supertype method

Shouldn't it accept any type of FilterAbs as it's argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the signature is different.

So you have `public void saveFilter(FilterAbs filter);` in your interface and

`public void saveFilter(JobFilter jobFilter)` in your code.

**Please note** that `public` is also redundant in your interface. It is implicitly `public` by default.

You can use a generic interface to alleviate this problem:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T extends FilterAbs> {
    public T getFilter(String filterName);
    public void saveFilter(T filter);
}
```

Although it is not perfectly clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm not sure why using a super type for the return type works ok, but not for method arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Because the method is different, it has a different argument and therefore different signature

```
public void saveFilter(FilterAbs filter);
public void saveFilter(JobFilter jobFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

To override you  need exact method signature.

```
@Override
public void saveFilter(FilterAbs jobFilter)
//Do stuff
}
```

Comment: If that's the case why does `@Override public JobFilter getFilter(String filterName)` work ok?